# Ensuring Proper Return Type transmission between array of promises

Tags: typescript

How can I ensure that the return type of the `assertAuthenticated` function is transmitted to the `demoMiddleware` function, and the return type of the last promise in the array is conveyed to the `async (request)` callback handler in this scenario?

[ts playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NdJ86W)

```
import { CallableRequest, HttpsError } from 'firebase-functions/v2/https'

export type Handler<T> = (request: CallableRequest<T>) => Promise<unknown>

export type Middleware<T = unknown> = (
  request: CallableRequest<T>,
  next: Handler<T>,
) => Promise<unknown>

export const withMiddlewares = <T>(
  middlewares: Middleware<any>[],
  handler: Handler<T>,
) => {
  const chainMiddlewares: (middlewares: Middleware<T>[]) => Handler<T> = (
    middlewares,
  ) => {
    const chain: Handler<T> = async (request) => {
      if (middlewares.length === 0) {
        return handler(request)
      }

      const [firstMiddleware, ...restOfMiddlewares] = middlewares
      try {
        return await firstMiddleware(request, (nextData) => {
          return chainMiddlewares(restOfMiddlewares)(nextData)
        })
      } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error)
      }
    }

    return chain
  }

  return chainMiddlewares(middlewares)
}

export const assertAuthenticated: Middleware = (request, next) => {
  if (!request.auth?.uid) {
    throw new HttpsError('unauthenticated', 'Unauthorized.')
  }
  return next(request)
}

const demoMiddleware: Middleware = (request, next) => {
  return next({ ...request, data: { demo: 'demo123' } })
}

withMiddlewares(
  [assertAuthenticated, demoMiddleware],
  async (request) => {
    console.log(request.data.demo) // 'request.data' is of type 'unknown'
  },
)
```

Comment: Is this question really dependent on google-cloud-functions?  If not you might consider producing a [mre] that doesn't need it, so that the question and its answer are more generally applicable to TypeScript.